# C++ standard for member offsets of standard layout struct

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

Does the C++11 standard guarantee that all compilers will choose the same memory offsets for all members in a given standard layout struct, assuming all members have guaranteed sizes (e.g. `int32_t` instead of `int`)?

That is, for a given member in a standard layout struct, does C++11 guarantee that `offsetof` will give the same value across all compilers?

If so, is there any specification of what that value would be, e.g. as a function of size, alignment, and order of the struct members?

Comment: The offset of the member also depends on alignment and padding, which are dependent on the platform (as well as the member types).  You may be able to get more consistent by having the compiler pack the items or you insert padding elements (instead of the compiler).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no guarantee that offsetof will yield the same values across compilers.

There are guarantees about minimum sizes of types (e.g., `char` >= 8 bits, `short`, `int` >= 16 bits, `long` >= 32 bits, `long long` >= 64 bits), and the relationship between sizes<sup>1</sup> (`sizeof(char)` <= `sizeof(short)` <= `sizeof(int)` <= `sizeof(long)` <= `sizeof(long long)`).

For most types, it's guaranteed that the alignment requirement is no greater than the size of the type.

For any `struct`/`class`, the first (non-static<sup>2</sup>) element must be at the beginning of the `class`/`struct`, and in the absence of changes to the visibility, order is guaranteed to be in the order of definition. For example:

```cpp
struct { // same if you use `class`
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Since these are both public, `a` and `b` must be in that order. But:

```cpp
struct {
    int a;
    int b;
private:
    int c;
};
```

The first element (`a`) is required to be at the beginning of the struct, but because of the change from `public` to `private`, the compiler is (theoretically) allowed to arrange `c` before `b`.

This rule has changed over time though. In C++98, even a vacuous visibility specifier allowed rearrangement of members.

```cpp
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    int c;
};
```

The `public` allows rearranging `b` and `c` even though they're both public. Since then it's been tightened up so it's only elements with differing visibility, and in C++ 23 the whole idea of rearranging elements based on visibility is gone (and long past time, in my opinion--I don't think anybody ever used it, so it's always been a rule you sort of needed to know, but did nobody any real good).

---

1. If you want to get really technical, the requirement isn't really on the size, but on the range, so in theory the relationship between sizes isn't quite guaranteed, but for for most practical purposes, it is.
2. A static element isn't normally allocated as part of the class/struct object at all. A static member is basically allocated as  a global variable, but with some extra rules about visibility of its name.

Comment: @Aconcagua With C++23 this restriction to same access control will be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

No, there are no such guarantees. The C++ standard explicitly provides for type-specific padding and alignment requirements, for one thing, and that automatically dissolves this kind of guarantee.

It might be reasonable to anticipate uniform padding and alignment requirements for a specific hardware platform, that all compilers on that platform will implement, but that again is not guaranteed.

Comment: Not only are there not guarantees, but in fact different compilers do actually make different choices on the same platforms (e.g., Microsoft C++ and at least some ports of gnu C++ use different sizes for `bool` on exactly the same hardware and OS).

Comment: Compilers (or ports) make different choices, even on the same platform for a range of reasons (e.g. tailoring to better support embedded).   Some compilers also provide a range of compilation options that either explicitly or implicitly affect choices related to sizes, alignment of types, or (within structures) padding.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not. Memory layout is completely up to the C++ implementation. The only exception, only for standard-layout classes, is that the first non-static data member or base class subobject(s) have zero offset. There are also some other constraints, e.g. due to sizes and alignment of subobjects and constraints on ordering of addresses of subobjects, but nothing that determines concrete offsets of subobjects.

However, typically compilers follow some ABI specification on any given architecture/platform, so that compilers for the same architecture/platform will likely use the same ABI and same memory layout (e.g. the SysV x86-64 ABI together with the Itanium C++ ABI on Linux x86-64 at least for both GCC and Clang).